# How to use __DEV__ without Flow errors

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I'm using Flow in React Native and when using `__DEV__` I get a Flow error and I don't know where to fix it.

Example:

```js
console.log(__DEV__ ? "development" : "production", "mode");

Flow (InferError)
Cannot resolve name '__DEV__'
```

Even the Intellisense for `__DEV__` is there!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `__DEV__` is defined in the [Flow repo](https://github.com/facebook/flow/search?q=__DEV__&unscoped_q=__DEV__) so you'll have to declare it yourself with

```
declare var __DEV__: boolean;
```

See [Declaring A Global Variable](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-a-global-variable) for more information.